# Named Credentials I couldn't pass API key to Apex ==> Authentication Protocol Custom ==> Principals *Name = apiKey *Value=*********

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

```java
public class WeatherDetailsClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static WeatherDetailsWrapper getWeatherDetails(String cityName) {
        // Frame the Endpoint URL
        String apiKey = '**************************';
        String endpoint = 'callout:Open_Weather/data/2.5/weather';
        endpoint += '?q=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(cityName, 'UTF-8'); // Ensure city name is URL encoded
        endpoint += '&units=metric';
        endpoint += '&APPID=' + apiKey;
        system.debug('Endpoint URL=> ' + endpoint);

        // Callout to Weather API with retry mechanism
        HttpResponse res = performWeatherApiCallout(endpoint);
```

I'm trying to get apikey like this

```java
//;

// Retrieve API Key from Named Credential
    String apiKey = getApiKey();
    if (apiKey == null) {
      // Handle case where API key is not found
      return null;
    }
```

Helper method to retrieve API Key from Named Credential

```java
private static String getApiKey() {
    NamedCredential credential = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM NamedCredential WHERE DeveloperName = 'Open_Weather' LIMIT 1];
    if (credential != null) {
      return credential.Value; // Assuming the API Key is stored in the Value field
    } else {
      return null; // Handle case where Named Credential is not found
    }
}
```

> Variable does not exist: Value (54:25)

My External Credentials ==> Authentication Protocol
Custom   ==> Principals *Name = apiKey *Value=*********

How I can add to apikey at my endpoint?

`endpoint += '&APPID=' + apiKey;`

Comment: I've attempted to break things up into logical sections, but what you have written is still somewhat confusing.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear though. `value` isn't a field on the `NamedCredential` object (and even if it were, you would need to query for it before you could access it). Kinda the entire point of NamedCredentials is that you're having Salesforce manage the obtaining and subsequent insertion/use of access tokens.

Comment: Having the api key included as a query parameter instead of in an HTTP header may not be supported. I mean, you could try to use a similar method to [sfdcfox's approach in this other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217282/24889). There's also [Use API Keys with Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&type=5) (which is basically the same thing but for the "new" named credentials). This may be something better suited for a Custom Metadata Type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Named Credential merge fields as URL parameters on the endpoint?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139116/can-i-use-named-credential-merge-fields-as-url-parameters-on-the-endpoint)